# How to stop / kill my current test case?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, mockito, robolectric

I want to stop the execution of a test if it matches a certain scenario in order to avoid code duplication.

Consider the following situation:

**CoreProviderTest**

```
  public void executeCoreSuccess(Object responseModel){
     assertNotNull("Response successful", responseModel != null);

     if (responseModel == null) {
        //Kill Test
     }
  }
```

**ChildProviderTest** *- extends CoreProviderTest*

```
 @Test
public void responseTester() {

    new Provider().getServiceResponse(new Provider.Interface() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object responseModel) {
            executeCoreSuccess(responseModel);
            //Continue assertions
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(ErrorResponseModel error) {
            executeCoreFailure(error);
        }
    });
}
```

For a null response, I would like to kill my current test case inside CoreProviderTest otherwise that might trigger exceptions in further assertions. I wanted to avoid something like:

**CoreProviderTest**

```
if (responseModel == null) {
    return true;
}
```

**ChildProviderTest**

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Object responseModel) {
   if (executeCoreSuccess(responseModel))
       return;

     //Continue assertions
}
```

Is there a way to kill the current test execution with Mockito, JUnit or Roboletric? No luck so far googling an answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [assumes](https://github.com/junit-team/junit.contrib/tree/master/assumes) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JUnit Assumptions](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html) suits perfect to the given case.

Code snippet now stands like:

**CoreProvider**

```
 public void executeCoreSuccess(Object responseModel){
    assumeTrue("Response successful",responseModel != null);
 }
```

According to JUnit's documentation:

> A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the
>   test provides no useful information. Assume basically means "don't run
>   this test if these conditions don't apply". The default JUnit runner
>   skips tests with failing assumptions.

+1 Adelin and Dossani

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JUnit5, it has features like Assumtions, Disabling tests and Conditional Test Execution.
Here's the link :

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assumptions

In your case, looks like assumingThat should work. Here's the API :
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assumptions.html#assumingThat-boolean-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-